# When the app starts for the first time, the picture starts to flicker. After restarting, this issue is resolved. Why?

Tags: java, android, crash

When the app starts for the first time, the picture starts to flicker after the login. After restarting, this issue is resolved. Is the error in `MainActivity.java` or in the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

[image]

I get an error with Android Studio. Only one `ViewPointer` 0 is always displayed.

Thanks for your help!

Here's my `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Fragment selectedfragment = null;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    private DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

        BottomNavigationView bottom_navigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);

        bottom_navigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.home).setChecked(true);

        Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (intent != null) {
            String publisher = intent.getString("publisherid");

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("profileid", publisher);
            editor.apply();

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new ProfileFragment()).commit();
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new HomeFragment()).commit();
        }

        ImageButton ClickImageButton = findViewById(R.id.btnLaunchCamera);
        ImageButton ClickImageButton2 = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        ClickImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostActivity.class));
            }
        });

        ClickImageButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, OptionsActivity.class));
            }
        });

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView_home);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private final BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.chat_notification:
                            selectedfragment = new ChatNotificationFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.home:
                            selectedfragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.profile:
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString("profileid", Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid());
                            editor.apply();
                            selectedfragment = new ProfileFragment();
                            break;
                    }
                    if (selectedfragment != null) {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedfragment).commit();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            };

    private void status(String status){
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("status", status);

        reference.updateChildren(hashMap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        status("online");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        status("offline");
    }
}
```

And the `LoginActivity.class`

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        Button login = findViewById(R.id.login);
        TextView txt_signup = findViewById(R.id.txt_signup);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        txt_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pd.show();

                String str_email = email.getText().toString();
                String str_password = password.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str_email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(str_password)){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "All fields are required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(str_email, str_password)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                                                .child(Objects.requireNonNull(auth.getCurrentUser()).getUid());

                                        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                pd.dismiss();
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                finish();
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                                pd.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        pd.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's my logcat which I found relevant.

```
2019-05-21 18:29:22.997 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@bb9034b[LoginActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2220) ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
2019-05-21 18:29:39.044 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@bb9034b[LoginActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
2019-05-21 18:29:39.122 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@bb9034b[LoginActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
2019-05-21 18:29:39.136 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/Dialog: mIsSamsungBasicInteraction = false
2019-05-21 18:29:39.137 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/Dialog: mIsSamsungBasicInteraction = false, isMetaDataInActivity = false
2019-05-21 18:29:39.326 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
2019-05-21 18:29:39.362 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
2019-05-21 18:29:39.426 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=82
2019-05-21 18:29:39.427 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@1f3d2b6[LoginActivity]: setView = DecorView@dc85bb7[LoginActivity] TM=true MM=false
2019-05-21 18:29:39.431 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@caff24
2019-05-21 18:29:39.474 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@1f3d2b6[LoginActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
2019-05-21 18:29:39.510 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@1f3d2b6[LoginActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,72][1080,2220] new=[27,972][1053,1320] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 486703767552} changed=true
2019-05-21 18:29:39.515 28351-28798/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2019-05-21 18:29:39.515 28351-28798/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x7150d8a680, 0x7151ce2010
2019-05-21 18:29:39.534 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@1f3d2b6[LoginActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
2019-05-21 18:29:39.602 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@1f3d2b6[LoginActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(27, 972 - 1053, 1320) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
2019-05-21 18:29:39.630 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@bb9034b[LoginActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
2019-05-21 18:29:39.630 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@3c97128[LoginActivity]
2019-05-21 18:29:39.631 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2019-05-21 18:29:40.140 28351-28367/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( LrSnbTOnxtZZ8rZ4QqL99532pjd2 ).
2019-05-21 18:29:40.140 28351-28367/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about user ( LrSnbTOnxtZZ8rZ4QqL99532pjd2 ).
2019-05-21 18:29:40.245 28351-29180/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-05-21 18:29:40.342 28351-29180/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/TcpOptimizer: TcpOptimizer-ON
2019-05-21 18:29:41.849 28351-28798/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7151ce2010 disconnect failed
2019-05-21 18:29:41.849 28351-28798/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x7150d8a680, 0x7151ce2000
2019-05-21 18:29:41.850 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@1f3d2b6[LoginActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
2019-05-21 18:29:41.852 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@1f3d2b6[LoginActivity]: Surface release. android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie:7931 android.view.ViewRootImpl.die:7899 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked:497 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView:435 android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate:124 android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog:518 android.app.Dialog.dismiss:501 com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo.LoginActivity$2$1$1.onDataChange:79 
2019-05-21 18:29:41.891 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=82
2019-05-21 18:29:41.929 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@bb9034b[LoginActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
2019-05-21 18:29:41.929 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@3c97128[LoginActivity]
2019-05-21 18:29:41.930 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2019-05-21 18:29:41.935 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
2019-05-21 18:29:41.942 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@32cd7d9[StartActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
2019-05-21 18:29:41.943 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@32cd7d9[StartActivity]: Surface release. android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie:7931 android.view.ViewRootImpl.die:7899 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked:497 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView:435 android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate:124 android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity:4722 android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute:39 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState:145 
2019-05-21 18:29:41.946 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=70
2019-05-21 18:29:41.953 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 26738
2019-05-21 18:29:41.963 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@bb9034b[LoginActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 0
2019-05-21 18:29:41.963 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2019-05-21 18:29:41.964 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@66cb77f
2019-05-21 18:29:41.988 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: onActivityCreated
2019-05-21 18:29:41.992 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Activity paused, time: 163765850
2019-05-21 18:29:42.058 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=26738, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LoginActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=4754157434908249509}]
2019-05-21 18:29:42.123 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2019-05-21 18:29:42.616 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=79
2019-05-21 18:29:42.617 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@9fd8955[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@d898f6a[MainActivity] TM=true MM=false
2019-05-21 18:29:42.672 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=LoginActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=4754157434908249509, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=4754157434908249510}]
2019-05-21 18:29:42.745 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2019-05-21 18:29:42.746 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2019-05-21 18:29:42.754 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 163766485
2019-05-21 18:29:42.786 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@9fd8955[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
2019-05-21 18:29:42.870 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@9fd8955[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,2220] new=[0,0][1080,2220] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 486689333248} changed=true
2019-05-21 18:29:42.881 28351-28798/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2019-05-21 18:29:42.881 28351-28798/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x7150af0e00, 0x7150f1e010
2019-05-21 18:29:42.963 28351-28798/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7150ddc010 disconnect failed
2019-05-21 18:29:42.963 28351-28798/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x7150af0800, 0x7150ddc000
2019-05-21 18:29:42.979 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@bb9034b[LoginActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,2220] new=[0,0][1080,2220] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
2019-05-21 18:29:42.988 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 402
2019-05-21 18:29:42.989 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2019-05-21 18:29:42.997 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Activity paused, time: 163766886
2019-05-21 18:29:43.079 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/FA: Connected to remote service
2019-05-21 18:29:43.079 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@88c147d
2019-05-21 18:29:43.087 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 5
2019-05-21 18:29:43.108 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: onActivityCreated
2019-05-21 18:29:43.230 28351-28359/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo I/ect.bbinktatto: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
2019-05-21 18:29:43.519 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=85
2019-05-21 18:29:43.520 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@2045607[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@e78f334[MainActivity] TM=true MM=false
2019-05-21 18:29:43.538 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2019-05-21 18:29:43.565 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=4754157434908249510, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=4754157434908249511}]
2019-05-21 18:29:43.661 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@2045607[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
2019-05-21 18:29:43.683 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 163767391
2019-05-21 18:29:43.731 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@2045607[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,2220] new=[0,0][1080,2220] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 486702960640} changed=true
2019-05-21 18:29:43.744 28351-28798/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2019-05-21 18:29:43.744 28351-28798/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x714aef7800, 0x7151c1d010
2019-05-21 18:29:43.860 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for views found on class com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo.model.Story
2019-05-21 18:29:43.863 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for views found on class com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo.model.Story
2019-05-21 18:29:43.898 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 406
2019-05-21 18:29:43.924 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Activity paused, time: 163767797
2019-05-21 18:29:44.020 28351-28798/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7150f1e010 disconnect failed
2019-05-21 18:29:44.020 28351-28798/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x7150af0e00, 0x7150f1e000
2019-05-21 18:29:44.184 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
2019-05-21 18:29:45.047 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@9fd8955[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,2220] new=[0,0][1080,2220] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
2019-05-21 18:29:45.108 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for views found on class com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo.model.Story
2019-05-21 18:29:45.110 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for views found on class com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo.model.Story
2019-05-21 18:29:45.135 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@6a289c6
2019-05-21 18:29:45.152 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: onActivityCreated
2019-05-21 18:29:45.403 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=86
2019-05-21 18:29:45.404 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@dc47a7c[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@1e21f05[MainActivity] TM=true MM=false
2019-05-21 18:29:45.406 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo I/Choreographer: Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2019-05-21 18:29:45.456 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=4754157434908249511, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=4754157434908249512}]
2019-05-21 18:29:45.574 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 163769278
2019-05-21 18:29:46.050 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@dc47a7c[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
2019-05-21 18:29:46.083 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@dc47a7c[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,2220] new=[0,0][1080,2220] result=0x1 surface={valid=false 0} changed=false
2019-05-21 18:29:46.105 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo E/ViewRootImpl@dc47a7c[MainActivity]: Surface is not valid.
2019-05-21 18:29:46.123 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for views found on class com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo.model.Story
2019-05-21 18:29:46.126 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo I/chatty: uid=10415(com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo) identical 2 lines
2019-05-21 18:29:46.127 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for views found on class com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo.model.Story
2019-05-21 18:29:46.205 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 826
2019-05-21 18:29:46.222 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Activity paused, time: 163770103
2019-05-21 18:29:46.246 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for views found on class com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo.model.Story
2019-05-21 18:29:46.247 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for views found on class com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo.model.Story
2019-05-21 18:29:46.248 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for views found on class com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo.model.Story
2019-05-21 18:29:46.250 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for views found on class com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo.model.Story
2019-05-21 18:29:46.280 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@14ac2e2
2019-05-21 18:29:46.311 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: onActivityCreated
2019-05-21 18:29:46.570 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=89
2019-05-21 18:29:46.571 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@7fd8c45[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@a0fef9a[MainActivity] TM=true MM=false
2019-05-21 18:29:46.599 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2019-05-21 18:29:46.616 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=4754157434908249512, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=4754157434908249513}]
2019-05-21 18:29:46.732 28351-28746/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 163770442
2019-05-21 18:29:46.873 28351-28798/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7151c1d010 disconnect failed
2019-05-21 18:29:46.873 28351-28798/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x714aef7800, 0x7151c1d000
2019-05-21 18:29:47.096 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@2045607[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,2220] new=[0,0][1080,2220] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
2019-05-21 18:29:47.123 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@7fd8c45[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
2019-05-21 18:29:47.144 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo D/ViewRootImpl@7fd8c45[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,2220] new=[0,0][1080,2220] result=0x1 surface={valid=false 0} changed=false
2019-05-21 18:29:47.154 28351-28351/com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo E/ViewRootImpl@7fd8c45[MainActivity]: Surface is not valid.
```

Comment: Do you see anything special in your logcat? Please post your logcat as well.

Comment: I hope you know what you are doing. Little fun. I hope you can start with the Logcat. I noticed this here: `Skipped 33 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread`

Answer (score 0):

I am exactly sure about the problem you are having. However, I can point out some things which I found useful considering when you are changing your code to solve the problem.

First, let us consider the following message.

> No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

You need to setup your network configuration as specified following the [guideline here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-network-security-config/#0).

> Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
>   main thread

As you have mentioned already, your application is doing too much works in its main thread. And hence, you need to check if there's a possibility of moving anything in a background task so that the main thread is doing only things necessary to populate the initial views.

> No setter/field for views found on class
>   com.bbinkconnect.bbinktattoo.model.Story

Please check this class and write setters for views and make the setters public.

After logging in, I think you are loading the `HomeFragment` which is doing too much work in the main thread. If it is loading images in the main thread from network, consider using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

I hope that helps!

Comment: I will check everything you have written to me. I'll contact you when the work is done. I thank you already now. Thank you! :D

Comment: Let me know if there's anything else. :)

Comment: Forgive me my way, but I do not look through where I can make the main thread easier. (Yes I know ... debugging is hard and not easy.) Would you help me to solve the problem? (My main thread in my head is also overloaded.) I'll grapple alone with the getter, setter, and of course the Network Security Configuration.